# Number of ways to arrange people in straight line and round table.

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations

I have the solution to 2 counting questions. But I do not understand why in Q1, it is $2!$ but in Q2 it is $(2!)^5$. These steps in my understanding takes account for order within each "group" of 2. But why in Q2 it is to the power of 5?

Q1
How many ways can 4 men and 4 women line up, if gender alternates?
Number of ways = ways to line up men $\times$ ways to line up women $\times$ MW or WM
= $4! \times 4! \times 2!$

Q2
In how many ways can 5 married couple sit around a circular table if each couple sits together?
Number of ways = number of ways to arrange 5 couples in round table $\times$ spouse 1,2 or spouse 2,1
=$\frac{5!}{5} \times (2!)^5 = 4! \times (2!)^5$

Comment: In the second question you can choose the order of the two people in each couple, and there are $5$ couples.

Comment: In Q1 it either goes MWMWMWMW or WMWMWMWM so two possibilities.  In Q2 each of the five couples can sit either way round

Comment: Because for the circular arrangement question we do not care that women and men alternate... It could have been clockwise around the table the order Mr. A, Mrs. A, Mrs. B, Mr. B, Mr. C, Mrs. C etc... or it could also have been Mr. A, Mrs. A, Mr. B, Mrs. B, Mrs. C, Mr. C, etc...  The only requirement was that spouses sit together.  There is no requirement about gender like in the first.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.